# Como criar uma estrutura de tópicos com Jekyll / Liquid

Tags: node.js, github, jekyll

Estou tentando criar uma estrutura de tópicos para simular um menu com link direto para o post.
Esta estrutura seria parecida com os manuais de ajuda por tópicos ou como a estrutura de capítulos dos livros.

O problema é como fazer, pensei em criar a estrutura no config.yml definindo uma tag e um titulo para cada tópico e verificando recursivamente se existe um sub-tópico. Não acho que seja a maneira mais correta, mas gerei uma estrutura assim:

http://pastebin.com/k07yPmAq

Como eu percorreria esta array, imprimindo os titulos e os posts correspondentes a estas tags?

Ou existe forma melhor?

Obs.: Isto ficará no GitHub, então, não posso usar plugins.

Comment: Porque não usas um `.json`? algo como : http://jsfiddle.net/87n3y798/ ou o Jekyll usa `.yml`?

Comment: O jekyll usa um arquivo .yml para configurações :)

Comment: ainda precisa da resposta?

Comment: Sim, ainda aguardo solução eficaz